# JavaScript консоль на телефоне

Tags: javascript, консоль, браузер

Как можно открыть JavaScript консоль в браузере на телефоне?

Comment: никак, телефонные браузеры этого (обычно) не предусматривают. Максимум - можно подключить телефон к компьютеру и открыть консоль для страницы открытой на телефоне в компьютере

Comment: Да и смысла нет подумайте ведь дебажить скрипты на телефоне ой как "удобно"

Comment: @AzizUmarov, насчет удобства можно поспорить, все зависит от размеров телефона и правильного gui

Comment: я просто написал игру браузерную (крестики-нолики), и хотелось-бы, если когда-то от скуки на уроке станет скучно, с другом поиграем (на телефоне же удобнее, чем на бумаге, особенно, если сам это написал :) ). Так вот, если друг начнет выигрывать, то открою консоль, пропишу секретную команду и там что-то интересное произойдёт. Поэтому вот и спрашиваю) Думаю, будет удобно, 6,7 дюймов телефон.

Comment: @ВладимирПечерский, Вам никто не запрещает поставить скрытый элемент который может появиться от каких-то действий. И вот там и вводите свои команды

Comment: @ВладимирПечерский вот ваш коммент лучше в вопрос - вам сразу кучу вариантов накидают, как можно сделать пасхалки.

Answer (score 3):

На самом телефоне не удастся. Можно использовать удаленную отладку на Android с Chrome. Подробнее по ссылке [тут](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging)

Представить DevTools на телефоне. Страх и только. На десктопном то там закладок, информации, опции и куча всего.

Answer (score 2):

В Google Play маркет есть приложения, позволяющие это сделать, но, в большинстве случаев, они крайне неудобные. Попробуй поискать что-то вроде "Inspector Browser", "Javascript console Browser".